# Is there any way to delete a topic in kafka-node

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any way to delete a topic in kafka-node? I have searched some documents but there are steps to remove a topic using kafka-node. I want to delete the topic instead of removing

Comment: What is the difference between deleting and removing?

Comment: By "remove" I believe he just means "stop listening".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to delete a topic using `kafka-node`. There's probably a way to do it via `node-zookeeper-client`, but that's non-standard. You'd have to look at the way the standard Kafka delete topic command does it, and then roll your own deletion code.

But regardless -- you can't do it via `kafka-node`.